# Functional equation and normal distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, functional-equations, characteristic-functions

Let $\alpha \neq 1.$

**If  $X,Y$ are two independent random variable such that $U=X+Y$ and $V=X+\alpha Y$ are independent, then $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed.**

In term of characteristic functions this means that $$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, \phi_X(x+y)\phi_Y(x+\alpha y)=\phi_X(x)\phi_Y(x)\phi_X(y)\phi_Y(\alpha y) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (E)$$

The particular case where $\alpha=-1$ was treated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3822099/normal-distribution-magic).

Trying to use that way for the general case didn't work.

**The main problem is how to solve the functional equation $(E).$**

Is it possible to find a functional equation $(E_1)$ which only depends of $\phi_X$ and $(E_2)$ which only depends of $\phi_Y$?

(We should find $|\phi_X(x)|=e^{x^2c_1},|\phi_Y(x)|=e^{c_2x^2},c_1,c_2 \leq 0$)

Comment: This is a consequence of the [Darmois–Skitovich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darmois%E2%80%93Skitovich_theorem).

Comment: The equation is solved:  A. Kagan, Yu. Linnik and C. Rao, Characterization problems of mathematical statistics, K. Wiley and Sons, NY, 1973 (translated from the Russian)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/385824/76416